# Printf multiple variables but no comma in between

Tags: c

I'm new to C and have spent a good amount of time trying to find this answer to avail so I thought I would turn to the brain trust.

I need to print out two values int and hex and there should be no comma in between went sent to the screen. This may be a case of the answer being so obvious that I'm just not looking at it right but here we go.

I have the code

```
printf(" %10d, 0x%X\n", answer, answer);
```

and it prints out as

```
5214, 0x145E
```

but I need it with no comma, just

```
5214 0x145E
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple. Just remove the comma from between.

```
printf(" %10d 0x%X\n", answer, answer);
```

This should do it.

Comment: I tried removing the commas in all the places but that one. Thanks so much. It was much as I assumed it would be, an easy answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. Just remove the comma from between.

```
printf(" %10d 0x%X\n", answer, answer);
```

**Output:**

```
5214 0x145E
```

`printf` will print anything return between Double Inverted commas("").

Answer (score 1):

```
printf(" % % ", , );
```

Whatever you write between the " " will get printed. The number of % in " " will be the number of values you want to print, so they are separated by commas later.

Answer (score 0):

What is there to ask about you can simply do :-

```
printf(" %10d 0x%X\n", answer, answer);
```

And You'll have your output like this:-

```
5214 0x145E
```

You can also include tabs to provide space between them like

```
printf(" %10d \t 0x%X\n", answer, answer);
```

The answer will look like this:-

```
5214           0x145E
```

Comment: sorry, i tried to do it right when it was answered but I needed to wait 5 minutes per rules and during that 5 minutes I ended going to bed after finding my school's network server was down.